# Configuring a bitbucket repository to "activate" pipelines

Tags: bitbucket-api, bitbucket-pipelines

I have multiple repositories in a BitBucket project.
I wish to automatically create a bitbucket repository, and enable pipelines (setting the pipeline configuration should be easy, with pushing a bitbucket-pipelines.yml file).
How can I do it using the REST API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a repository with the BitBucket REST API.

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
    "scm": "git",
    "project": {
        "key": "Foo"
    }
}' https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/<username>/<repo_slug>
```

Push your `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` to your created repo.

```
curl https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/<username>/<slug>/src \
    -F /bitbucket-pipelines.yml=@bitbucket-pipelines.yml
```

Then **enable** pipeline for your project

```
curl -X PUT -is -u '<username>:<password>' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/<username>/<repo_slug> \
 -d '{ 
        "enabled": true,
        "type": "repository_pipelines_configuration"
    }'
```

Finally, you can **trigger a pipeline** for the branch like so.

```
$ curl -X POST -is -u <username>:<password> \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
 https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/<username>/<slug>/pipelines/ \
  -d '
  {
    "target": {
      "ref_type": "branch", 
      "type": "pipeline_ref_target", 
      "ref_name": "<branch_name>"
    }
  }'
```

#### References:

- [Repository API](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D#postr)
- [Pipelines API](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/pipelines/#post)

Comment: Does pushing a bitbucket-pipelines.yml to your sources enable automatically pipeline ? Don't you need to enable it ?

Comment: I found the request to enable pipeline 

    curl -X PUT -is -u '<username>:<password>' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/<name/<project>/pipelines_config \
    -d '{
        "enabled": true,
        "type": "repository_pipelines_configuration"
    }'

Comment: Yes, the pipeline addon needs to be enabled first to use the pipeline endpoint.

Comment: @Mektoub, you can edit the answer with the information to enable pipeline

Comment: This answer is out of date. You must use the pipelines_config endpoint to enable pipelines, as in Michal Tenenberg's answer.

Answer (score 9):

The other answer's "enable pipelines" request did not work for me.
This is what worked:

```
curl -X PUT -is -u '<username>:<password>' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/<username>/<slug>/pipelines_config \
 -d '{
        "enabled": true
    }'
```

Comment: It looks like Bitbucket updated their rest API references so that the accepted answer is no longer valid. This answer is currently most up to date.